# $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is a unique factorization domain.

My approach is to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is a PID, which implies that it is a UFD.

Proof:

Suppose there exists an ideal $I$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ such that it is generated by two or more elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$. That is, $I = \langle g_1(x), g_2(x), ..., g_n(x)\rangle$. Then $I=\{a_1(x)g_1(x)+a_2(x)g_2(x)+...+a_n(x)g_n(x):a_i(x)\in \mathbb{Z}_5[x] \}$. Consider $\max\{a_i(x)g_i(x)\}=\deg_{max} (I)$. Then, since $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a PID, $\langle a_i(x)g_i(x)\rangle = \langle g_1(x), g_2(x), ..., g_n(x)\rangle$. Hence, $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is a PID. This implies that $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is a UFD.

It would be interesting to know one's opinion on my proof.

Comment: Presumably you mean that $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ is a PID, not $\mathbb Z_5$.

Comment: I don't understand how $I$ is defined: on the right side of the colon, in the set builder notation, on expects some *property*? You don't have a property, but a combination of polynomials, i.e. a mathematical object. In other words, your definition is meaningless.

Comment: You are supposing that every ideal is finitely generated. It's an easier route to use the well-ordering principle followed by the fact that there is a division algorithm for polynomials over a field.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, corrected that.

Comment: And what is $\deg_{\max}(I)$?

Comment: @Bernard The maximal degree of a summand in the generator of $I$.

Comment: This is very confusing… What is a summand in the  generator (s, I guess)?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the maximal degree of a term in the sum in the generator of $I$, presented by the set above.

Comment: @Oiler Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @sequence if you have a proper, nontrivial ideal then there exists a polynomial of minimal degree. Show that minimal polynomial generates the entire ideal by applying the division algorithm for polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

You have to use that, in a polynomial ring over a field, you can perform Euclidean divisions, and consider a non-zero polynomial of least degree in the ideal.

Comment: Do you mean the idea is to show that if there is a proper ideal $I$, which contains a polynomial $f(x)$ of minimum degree, then if we divide any polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ by $f(x)$, we will get $g(x) = f(x)q(x)+r(x)$, which is any polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$, and hence $I$ cannot be a proper ideal?

Comment: You have to show that if $g(x)\in I$, then $r(x)=0$, henace any polynomial in $I$ is divisible by $f(x)$. Same  argument as for showing $\mathbf Z$ (actually, all *Euclidean domains* are PIDs).

Answer (score 0):

By $\mathbb{Z}_5$ I assume you mean $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. This is a field, since 5 is prime. Any field is a PID. See [Why any field is a principal ideal domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415081/why-any-field-is-a-principal-ideal-domain)

EDIT: After comments, I realized that while the OP said, "My approach is to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a PID," what the OP **meant** to say was "My approach is to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is a PID." My answer, while a good answer to the first, is not a good answer to the second.

Comment: But they are asking about the polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, which is not a field.

Comment: I assumed that the OP was trying to show that $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, as is indicated in the post, but as @ThomasAndrews points out in the comment above, I may have misread.

Comment: @Oiler: But if $R$ is an UFD, then so is $R[X]$.

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter Then I would need to prove that if $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a PID then $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is a PID.

Comment: @HenningMakholm While true, it doesn't seem to be the route this answer is suggesting and is kind of a "big theorem" for this exercise.

Comment: @sequence: No, a polynomial ring over a PID which is not a field is never a PID.

Comment: @Bernard We know that $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a field.

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter Sorry that was a typo, fixed now.

Comment: @sequence: That's right, but the reason you invoked was only it's a PID, which is not a correct argument ($\mathbf Z[x]$ is *not* a PID).